# How to display string on html with <<Hello>> also same string will passed to json

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I want to set some value on html with special symbols. And I want same string into json also. But I'm not getting like that.

```
this.DTTodaysDateforJson = '<<Hello>>'
console.log("this.DTTodaysDateforJson",this.DTTodaysDateforJson);
//this.DTTodaysDateforJson <<Hello>> This is output for above console.
this.productDiscriptionArrayForID =  `${this.DTTodaysDateforJson} <br>&#8810;DV.Product.${this.selectedID}&#8811; <br> ${this.product.productDescription}`
console.log("this.selectedIDwithDiscription-----", this.productDiscriptionArrayForID);
//<<Hello>> getting this in console. But on HTML page it's getting only "<>" this.
```

How I can get << Hello >> without gap between "<< and Hello" for both this.productDiscriptionArrayForID and on html page. also.
this.productDiscriptionArrayForID is used for passing data to json.
And that data get added to html page using following code.

```
this.productForm.controls.des.setValue(this.productDiscriptionArrayForID);
```

I'm doing this in angualr11

Answer (score 0):

You need to HTML-encode the string before injecting it into an HTML context.

```
const htmlEncode = (s) => {
    const el = document.createElement("span");
    el.textContent = s;
    return el.innerHTML;
};
```

```
this.DTTodaysDateforJson = '<<Hello>>';
console.log("this.DTTodaysDateforJson",this.DTTodaysDateforJson);
this.productDiscriptionArrayForID =  `${htmlEncode(this.DTTodaysDateforJson)} <br>&#8810;DV.Product.${htmlEncode(this.selectedID)}&#8811; <br> ${htmlEncode(this.product.productDescription)}`
console.log("this.selectedIDwithDiscription-----", this.productDiscriptionArrayForID);
```

Alternatively, you could use [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) to automatically HTML-encode any content inserted into the string. For example:
[AntonioVdlC/html-template-tag: - ES6 Tagged Template for compiling HTML template strings](https://github.com/AntonioVdlC/html-template-tag)